# C# OleDbException was handled when fill Datatable

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to import multiple Excel sheets into a dataset in C#. 
And I get an error saying "OleDbException was unhandled" when it gets to `adp.Fill(dataTable);`

```
public static DataSet exceldata_intg(string filePath)
{
    OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + @"; Extended Properties=" + (char)34 + "Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;" + (char)34);
    DataSet data = new DataSet();


    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wSheet in excelBook.Worksheets)
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", wSheet);
        cnn.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(query,cnn);
        adp.Fill(dataTable); // this is where it causes error.
        data.Tables.Add(dataTable);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Also, I want to import each sheet starting from 13th row. 
Please help me with my code.

Comment: What is the _complete_ exception message exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül "The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'System.__ComObject'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'System.__ComObject' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator."

Comment: Don't deal with COM, it will be much slower. You can use LinqToExcel to read spreadsheets and it is much much easier than using COM. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659643/Csharp-Query-Excel-and-CSV-Files-Using-LinqToExcel

Comment: I dont think you can mix OleDb with com objects.  Note that the connection string is trying to open the **file** while you try tell it to query a com object

Comment: string query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", wSheet); wSheet is an objent, not a string. You should use the property were the name of the sheet is stored, not the object itself.